# Flutter packages pub global run webdev serve Error

Tags: flutter, dart

I have followed this tutorial step by step https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K_kBzJN8pAY and I am 100% sure that I did everything correctly but unfortunately I am getting this error:

> PS C:\MyApps\firstapp> flutter packages pub global run webdev serve
>   webdev could not run for this project. You must have a dependency on
>   `build_runner` in `pubspec.yaml`.
>
> **pubspec.yaml dev_dependencies:   build_runner: >=1.6.2 <2.0.0 You must have a dependency on `build_web_compilers` in `pubspec.yaml`.**
>
> **pubspec.yaml dev_dependencies:   build_web_compilers: >=1.2.0 <3.0.0 You have a dependency on `cupertino_icons` which is not supported for**
>
> flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more
>   details. You have a dependency on `flutter` which is not supported for
>   flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more
>   details. You have a dependency on `flutter_test` which is not
>   supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web
>   for more details. pub finished with exit code 78

Comment: Please provide every CODE what you have tried. We are not going to see that tutorial, implement in our system and find a solution. After seeing proper code, other contributors will have proper idea what's the problem in error.

Comment: run this command( flutter channel ) in terminal and add the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing has worked for me. In order to use flutter and dart, I used Android Studio.
It look like the problem is from Visual Studio Code.
Thanks for your help,
Jim

Answer (score 1):

If you follow that video exactly and did not change anything then you are on **stable** channel in flutter.

If You want to run flutter web then you have to move to **beta** channel.

Flutter web is under development, so it is only available on that channel.

check out here: https://flutter.dev/web

You can check channel by Following command.

> flutter channel

you can see Following output.

```
Flutter channels:
* master
  dev
  beta
  stable
```

In Your case may be star is in front of stable.

Run Following command to move to beta channel.

> Flutter channel beta

Now run following command to upgrade flutter.

> flutter upgrade

Now You are good to go.

Comment: Hello Viren,Thank you for your answer but unfortunately it did not work. You were right about me being on stable version.I followed your instruction Flutter channel beta to change to beta and i did the flutter upgrade but same :(

Comment: PS C:\MyApps\firstapp> flutter channel
Flutter channels:
  master
  dev
* beta
  stable                                                                                                                                    
PS C:\MyApps\firstapp> flutter upgrade
Upgrading Flutter from C:\flutter...
Already up to date.
Flutter is already up to date on channel beta
Flutter 1.14.6 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision fabeb2a16f (2 weeks ago) • 2020-01-28 07:56:51 -0800
Engine • revision c4229bfbba
Tools • Dart 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.5.0 fc3af737c7)

Comment: PS C:\MyApps\firstapp> flutter packages pub global run webdev serve
webdev could not run for this project.
You must have a dependency on `build_runner` in `pubspec.yaml`.
# pubspec.yaml
dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: >=1.6.2 <2.0.0 You must have a dependency on `build_web_compilers` in `pubspec.yaml`.
# pubspec.yaml
dev_dependencies:
  build_web_compilers: >=1.2.0 <3.0.0

Comment: You have a dependency on `cupertino_icons` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.
You have a dependency on `flutter` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.
You have a dependency on `flutter_test` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details.
pub finished with exit code 78

Comment: Did you try after adding build_runner(simple dependency) ,(build_runner: >=1.6.2 <2.0.0 ,build_web_compilers)(dev dependency) and remove cupertino_icons dependency.

Comment: Can you please explain more how to do that? Thanks in advance

Comment: Check out this link and understand everything about packages:https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages. Those dependency are required to run web project.

Comment: Just to make sure that i understand correctly you want me to add ( 
dependencies:
  build_runner: ^>=1.6.2 <2.0.0 ,build_web_compilers) in my pubspec.yaml file and remove (  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2) from my pubspec.yaml ?

Comment: the dependencies that is available in my pubspec.yaml is :
 dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

Comment: Accept the answer if you got solution, so other community members can also get benefit. @jimRezzi